# SQL return a value at a specific date in time

Tags: sql, date, select

I'm trying the find a value at a certain date.

My data looks like

```
Date        Value
2013-11-02   5
2013-10-10   8
2013-09-14   6
2013-08-15   4
```

How can I determine what the value was on 2013-09-30?

Obviously the answer is 6 but I can't figure out the SQL code.

Thanks

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: It is not really obvious that the answer is 6, since 2013-09-30 doesn't appear in your data. I assume now that the dates indicate state changes, and that the state (value) is maintained  at it's most recent value between dates. Id that's the case, you should make it clear in your question so that everyone's on the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `order by` and limiting the number of rows.  In SQL Server syntax (and Sybase and Access):

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
where date <= '2013-09-30'
order by date desc;
```

In MySQL (and Postgres):

```
select t.*
from table t
where date <= '2013-09-30'
order by date desc
limit 1;
```

In Oracle:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from table t
      where date <= '2013-09-30'
      order by date desc
    ) t
where rownum = 1
```

EDIT:

And, a SQL standard way to it (should work in any database):

```
select t.*
from table t
where date = (select max(date)
              from table t2
              where date <= '2013-09-30'
             );
```

Comment: Apologies for not being clearer, it is my first post. Thank you very much for your assistance, you have given me several options to run with.