# Show Value at specific date in spreadsheet - no queries

Tags: date, google-sheets

I would like to show a specific value at a certain date.

Example, I have a list of numbers and on Monday I want to count all the numbers that are in the list on that specific date. The list grows until Tuesday, so the number I will show on Tuesday will be bigger and so on.

Is there a non SQL solution for this? As I did find this thread:

[Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592252/sql-return-a-value-at-a-specific-date-in-time)

but I have no idea how to do SQL in spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give as an example of your data, because there are so many ways to do this depending on specifically what you want and how your data looks.

Comment: Of course! A2:A100 holds "warte auf GO" or "warte auf DATEN" or "Tester".

On Businessweek1 B1 holds: countif(A2:A100; "warte auf GO").
On Businessweek2 C1 holds: countif(A2:A100; "warte auf GO").

And so on. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Second question, do you want the number to show on specific day, or every Monday/Tuesday/Wednesday etc?

Comment: I would like the count to show in the first column on the first calendarweek, in the second column on the second calendarweek and so forth. 
So incremential and not in a repetitive loop if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

So you can try this:

On Businessweek1 B1

```
=if(AND(DAY(TODAY())>=1;DAY(TODAY())<=7;WEEKDAY(TODAY())=COLUMN(A1));countif(A2:A100; "warte auf GO");)
```

Then drag this across 7 columns.

On Businessweek2 B1

```
=if(AND(DAY(TODAY())>=8;DAY(TODAY())<=14;WEEKDAY(TODAY())=COLUMN(A1));countif(A2:A100; "warte auf GO");)
```

Then drag this across 7 columns.

And so on

Comment: Ok I tried it and do not get it.
1.I have weeknums in A2:AE1 right?
2.It gives me a #ref
3.It will always show me the value in A1 right? For that I can just use a "if"-sentence. What I am trying to do is show the value for each calendarweek (WEEKNUM) in a different column.

Comment: Sorry for confusion.
I would like to have one cell for one week. So I guess the "weeknum" function would be the solution?

Comment: weeknum is the number of the day in the week. You cannot actually get the number of the week in the month, that's why I used combination of Weeknum and Day

Comment: If you want to get the weeknumber of the month you will need to use script

Comment: But e.g. weeknum(today()) gives me 29 which is exactly the number of the current week!

Comment: I thought you meant the week of the month. You can probably just use =if(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=COLUMN(A1);countif(A2:A100; "warte auf GO");) then